# Debugging MS Exchange 2007 Transport Agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, exchange-server-2007, exchange-transport-agents

I have source code for a transport agent that I have installed on MS Exchange 2007 written in C#. I need to debug it using VS, which I think involves 'attaching' the debugger to the process 'MSExchangeTransport.exe'. I do this, and put in breakpoints as the first statement in the OnSubmittedMessageHandler(). I know that this handler is being called because the agent works as expected and the code in the handler carrying out it's duties. However I am not getting any debugging information in the debugging window (despite various Debug.WriteLine() calls) and when I hover the mouse over the breakpoints they say:

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document"

It was compiled in debug mode and successfully Installed and started using Install-TransportAgent, Enable-TransportAgent.

Something tells me the debugger is not finding what it needs. Any ideas?

Comment: Has the agent been compiled in debug mode?

Answer (score 2):

Ah! I should have been attaching the debugger to 'EdgeTransport.exe'. All working now.