# Exchange Server 2007 Transport Agent Issue

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2008, exchange-server-2007, exchange-transport-agents

This is the first time i am working on Exchange Server Development. Below is a simple Transport Agent that i am using, this agent should simply update the email Subjects as shown below in the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport;
using Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Smtp;



namespace MyAgents
{
    public sealed class MyAgentFactory : SmtpReceiveAgentFactory
    {
        public override SmtpReceiveAgent CreateAgent(SmtpServer server)
        {
            return new MyAgent();
        }
    }
    public class MyAgent : SmtpReceiveAgent
    {
        public MyAgent()
        {
            this.OnEndOfData += new EndOfDataEventHandler(MyEndOfDataHandler);
        }
        private void MyEndOfDataHandler(ReceiveMessageEventSource source, EndOfDataEventArgs e)
        {
            e.MailItem.Message.Subject = "This message passed through my agent: " + e.MailItem.Message.Subject;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Powershell script i am using to install the Agent.

```
Net Stop MSExchangeTransport
Install-TransportAgent -Name MyAgent -AssemblyPath EmailLogger.dll -TransportAgentFactory MyAgents.MyAgentFactory
Enable-TransportAgent -Identity MyAgent
Net Start MSExchangeTransport
```

Agent installed successfully using Exchange Management Shell.

Now when i send/receive emails in exchange, Email subjects are not modified. Emails have their original subjects. I don't know why?

I also performed the steps mentioned in below links to debug the Agent but breakpoints are not being hit by Visual Studio Debugger.

> http://www.sf-tools.net/Messaging/tabid/55/EntryId/163/Exchange-2010-Transport-Agent.aspx
>
> [Debugging MS Exchange 2007 Transport Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347123/debugging-ms-exchange-2007-transport-agent)
>
> http://omarjames.com/blog/index.php/debugging-exchange-transport-agent/

**My System Configuration**

I am using the Exchange Server 2007 Virtual Machine provided by Microsoft from link below

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=14901
```

I also installed the Visual Studio 2008 on the VM for debugging.

**Please help me in resolving the issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved. :)

I must use Routing Agent instead of SmtpReceive Agent because only Routing Agents are guaranteed to see all the Emails passing through Exchange Server.

Below is the modified working code, Everything else remains same

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport;
using Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.Routing;



namespace MyAgents
{
    public sealed class MyAgentFactory : RoutingAgentFactory
    {
        public override RoutingAgent CreateAgent(SmtpServer server)
        {
            return new MyAgent();
        }
    }
    public class MyAgent : RoutingAgent
    {
        public MyAgent()
        {
            this.OnSubmittedMessage += new SubmittedMessageEventHandler(this.MySubmittedMessageHandler);            
        }

        public void MySubmittedMessageHandler(SubmittedMessageEventSource source, QueuedMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.MailItem.Message.Subject = "This message passed through my agent: " + e.MailItem.Message.Subject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do u know how to "remove/delete" the mail if the subject contains a specific word?

Comment: Sorry, I left exchange server development. So no idea